# Rsyslog forwarding over HTTP

Tags: rsyslog

I would like rsyslog to forward log messages via **HTTP** to the service which will process them.

I don't see the exact **http-forwarding** module for Rsyslog, and I don't want to create another listener on another port just for handling incoming TCP connections, as it would be required with the TCP-output module.

Is it possible or what are the alternatives to process Rsyslog messages by HTTP handler?

Comment: I don't think such thing is available. Why don't put logs in database first and then perform the processing ?

Comment: @Luv33preet, technically possible, but then it is a +1 service, and I need to trigger custom events when specific event types appear -> querying DB every period of time, 1 min for example, because reaction should be as fast as possible

Comment: yes it is a +1 service. But in case you don't get any kind of HttpListener, maybe you can try the workaround I told you. Its not the best solution.

Comment: @Luv33preet, you propose to query DB every period of time?

Comment: I see two options: using an output that already does HTTP (Elasticsearch?), which means emulating that API. Or you can use omprog and plug your own script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rsyslog version 8.2202, there is the `omhttp` module.

Here is an example of what you'd need to implement in */etc/rsyslog.conf*:

```
# include the omhttp module
module(load="omhttp")

# template for each indivdual message, not the format of the resulting batch
template(name="tpl_omhttp_forwarding" type="string" string="%msg%")

# action to send ALL log (files) messages via http
*.* { 
    action(
        type="omhttp"
        server="192.1.1.1"
        serverport="443"
        template="tpl_omhttp_forwarding"

        batch="on"
        batch.format="jsonarray"
        batch.maxsize="10"

        action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
    )
}
```

All the action parameters for `omhttp`, you can find [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omhttp.html)

**NOTE:**

Depending on the OS you're using, you may need to build it yourself, or use the repositories [here](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Argerhards&package=rsyslog).
For some platforms, there is no `omhttp` package because of missing or too old dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new output module called omhttp. I'm looking into it as well, but am having difficulty finding documentation.

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3024

Edit: Updated docs are here
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omhttp.html#message-batching